# Java ошибка Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, maven, firewall, ipv6

Пытаюсь собрать программу DSpace. Получаю исключение следующего содержания:

```
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to
{s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Permission denied: connect
```

Привожу содержимое вывода CMD:

---

```
D:\DSpace_runtime\DSPACE\dspace>mvn package
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] DSpace Addon Modules
[INFO] DSpace Kernel :: Additions and Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace XML-UI (Manakin) :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace JSP-UI :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace RDF :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace REST :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace SWORD :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace SWORD v2 :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace SOLR :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace OAI-PMH :: Local Customizations
[INFO] DSpace Assembly and Configuration
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building DSpace Addon Modules 6.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-enforcer-plugin/1.4.1/maven-enforcer-plugin-1.4.1.pom
юъЄ 27, 2016 3:29:24 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.ex
ecchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to
 {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Permission denied: connect
юъЄ 27, 2016 3:29:24 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.ex
ecchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
юъЄ 27, 2016 3:29:45 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.ex
ecchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to
 {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Permission denied: connect
юъЄ 27, 2016 3:29:45 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.ex
ecchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
юъЄ 27, 2016 3:30:06 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.ex
ecchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when processing request to
 {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443: Permission denied: connect
юъЄ 27, 2016 3:30:06 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.ex
ecchain.RetryExec execute
INFO: Retrying request to {s}->https://repo.maven.apache.org:443
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] DSpace Addon Modules ............................... FAILURE [01:24 min]
[INFO] DSpace Kernel :: Additions and Local Customizations  SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace XML-UI (Manakin) :: Local Customizations .... SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace JSP-UI :: Local Customizations .............. SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace RDF :: Local Customizations ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace REST :: Local Customizations ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace SWORD :: Local Customizations ............... SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace SWORD v2 :: Local Customizations ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace SOLR :: Local Customizations ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace OAI-PMH :: Local Customizations ............. SKIPPED
[INFO] DSpace Assembly and Configuration .................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:24 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-27T15:30:27+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/21M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1 or one of it
s dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org
.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:jar:1.4.1: Could not transfer artifa
ct org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:pom:1.4.1 from/to central (htt
ps://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Permission denied: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResoluti
onException
```

---

Из рекомендаций в Интернете нашёл только использование опции Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, но она в моём случае не работает. Также рекомендуют отключить брандмауэр. Отключил. Также не работает. 
Ещё говорят, что это типичная ошибка Java 7, но на сайте Oracle не дают возможность скачать Java 6, мотивируя тем, что нужно пользоваться только последней версией, поэтому не могу подтвердить данную версию.

Выяснилось, что на сервере данное исключение не возникает, то есть DSpace собирается без ошибок. Возможно, сервер работает в обход некого firewall, но как это проверить, не знаю.

Comment: А почему бы 8 не скачать?

Comment: У меня восьмая и есть)))). Я думаю, проблема с седьмой версией актуальна и для восьмой.

Comment: А через браузер на той машине, на которой стартуется мавен, вы можете перейти по данному адресу https://repo.maven.apache.org:443 ?

Comment: Да. Все ссылки рабочие.

Comment: Вы работаете в офисе, у вас стоит прокси? Или из дома?

Comment: В офисе. Прокси в свойствах браузера не указан.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего прокси есть. Если его параметры неизвестны попробуйте сменить https протокол на http. Это можно сделать, например, через настройку профайла в вашем файле settings.xml

```html
<profiles> 
<profile>
  <id>central</id>
  <!--Override the repository (and pluginRepository) "central" from the Maven Super POM -->
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>central</id>
      <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</profile>
</profiles>
```

Далее необходимо активировать этот профайл

```html
<activeProfiles>
   <!--make the profile active all the time -->
   <activeProfile>central</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

На всякий случай ещё посмотрите настройку прокси [Configuring a proxy](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: Файла settings.xml у меня нет. Есть pom.xml. Похож на ваш, но в нём нет тегов <repository>.

Comment: Файл settings.xml у вас находится в вашем профайле OS в каталоге .m2. Например, для Windows 7 это будет `C:\Users\ВАШЕ_ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ\.m2\settings.xml`

Comment: Этого файла нет ни на моём компьютере, ни на сервере. В каталоге .m2 есть только подкаталог repository

Comment: Вам следует ознакомиться с этим - [Installing Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/install.html) и этим - [Configuring Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/configure.html)